# What does algebra $A \rtimes G$ stand for?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, notation, terminology

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $A$ a finite dimensional (unital associative) $k$-algebra of finite dimension, and $G$ a torus over $k$ acting on $A$.

What does $k$-algebra $A \rtimes G$ stand for? More specifically how to define addition, multiplication, and scaler multiplication?

The only usage of $\rtimes$ that I know is that of semidirect product and trivial extension algebra. But none of them make sense here. I came across this in the proposition 5.1 in [this paper](https://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S1474748011000089) ([alternative link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.1971)); the author says the statement is classic and doesn't explain what he meant by the symbol. Could you help me?

Comment: My guess (I don't really feel like reading through the arguments of a paper in French to see if I am right) is that it is the skew group algebra (see for example the book by Auslander-Reiren-Smalø for a reference). This is at least the most common thing to construct out of an algebra together with a group acting on it.

Comment: I only know this notation for the crossed product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossed_product

Comment: I don't have access to this paper. Can you quote the relevant proposition?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I added an alternative arXiv link.

Answer (score -2):

In a semidirect product $A\rtimes B$, the group $B$ acts on $A$. That is, there is a homomorphism from $B$ into $\operatorname{Aut}(A)$.

Here, you have $G$ acting on $A$, but in a different context. So maybe that is motivating using the notation $A\rtimes G$.

With *groups*, $A\rtimes B$ is the collection of pairs $(a,b)$, and there is a new group operation $(a_1,b_1)(a_2,b_2)=(a_1a_2^{b_1},b_1b_2)$ where $a_2^{b_1}$ is the image of $a_2$ under the action from $b_1$.

In OP's setting $A\rtimes G$ is the collection of pairs $(a,g)$, with $k(a,g)=(ka,g)=(a,kg)$. You again can have $(a_1,g_1)(a_2,g_2)=(a_1a_2^{g_1},g_1g_2)$, making $A\rtimes G$ an algebraic group. I'm not sure you can get an *algebra* out of this though, since the $G$ has no addition.

Comment: This does not really seem to answer the question.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Oh I see. I thought the product structure was clear but that OP was asking why use this notation. I'll edit.

Comment: I am not convinced the the edit has the correct structure. There are certainly ways to construct algebras from a group acting on an algebra (though the skew group algebra I mentioned is usually for finite groups acting on artin algebras, and I am not sure how far it generalizes).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yeah, I'm just guessing with the closest analogy to the semidirect product of two groups, since the notation is so commonly used for the semidirect product of groups. It could well mean something entirely different.

Comment: This is incorrect. If $G$ were just a group acting on an algebra $A$, then $A \rtimes G$ (which you might call, depending on taste, the semidirect product, the crossed product, or the skew group algebra...) would denote the *algebra* (not group) given by adjoining to $A$ an element $g$ for every $g \in G$ satisfying the relations in $G$ and the additional relations $grg^{-1} = \varphi(g) r$ where $\varphi(g)$ is the action. What's confusing about the OP's question is that $G$ is an algebraic group, not just a bare group.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I can accept that, but I'd suggest it has been a bad choice of notation if $A\rtimes G$ is not the same as $A\times G$ as _sets_.

Comment: @alex: I disagree. In fact the problem is that the semidirect product is in no sense a product. It's an example of a homotopy quotient.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The semiderect product is still a Cartesian product, set-wise; just with a different multiplication. Plenty of people might understand that without understanding what a homotopy quotient is, or even what homotopy is. I'm leaving this answer visible, since someone may find value in this comment thread. I don't mind if people want to add more down votes.

Comment: @alex: this is a misleading description of the semidirect product (for example, it does not correctly generalize to the case of algebras as we've seen here). It suggests, incorrectly, that the semidirect product has a universal property with respect to maps in. In fact the universal property is with respect to maps out.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It's a perfectly fine description of the semi-direct product for any undergraduate math student, the principle user base of this site.